# Datetime difference between two columns without counting the full 24 hours

Tags: python, pandas

here are two really useful questions for datetime comparison in python:

[Calculate Pandas DataFrame Time Difference Between Two Columns in Hours and Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu)

[Determine the difference between two DateTimes, only counting opening hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005983/determine-the-difference-between-two-datetimes-only-counting-opening-hours)

I have a dataframe in python with two columns:

```
A                      B
10:00:00 01.01.2019    12:00:00 02.01.2019
```

And I have opening hours (which are relevant hours), which only should count for the calculation, so not the full 24 hours and maybe not every day. So my business would be open from: 10:00:00 - 18:00:00 every day, how can i adjust:

```
df_time['td'] = df_time['B']-df_time['A']
```

That the outcome would be 10 hours in this case? And it is open from monday to friday.

Comment: What about weekends? there are excluded?

Comment: can be excluded. depending on the openomg hours

Comment: hmm, I answer something similiar and not so easy if want vectorized way. so is possible say need Monday to Friday at 10:00:00 - 18:00:00? Or 7 days in week?

Comment: lets say monday to friday 10:00 - 18:00, but ofr sure sometimes the monday can be also closed

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but I would do:

1. Count the time in the first day `18:00:00 - df['A'].dt.time`
2. Count the time in the last day  `df['B'] - 10:00:00`
3. Count the day in between and multiply by 8.