# Calculate the number of holidays between two dates in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for an Optimized Function which will return the number of public holidays and weekends between two given dates in C#

---

Actually the requirement is to combine holidays and weekends to create a good vacation plan for user. I dont need to worry about the country and religion because i have webservices to take care of getting holidays of a specific country and religion

Comment: What religions, which countries?  Too many variable ways to look at this and either way its not going to be a small solution which someone is going to whip up for you without proving you've tried to do this yourself.

Comment: This seems very difficult seeing as there are so many holidays, and it depends per country etc.

Comment: Here's a solution to calculate the number of work hours between two dates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3835137 If you have a method `bool IsHoliday(DateTime date)` you should be able to easily adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Your question can be split into two questions:

1. How to calculate holidays?
2. How to calculate the number of holidays between the two given ranges?

The first question has many answers. You could enter them in a data base, download from a website, look for a C# class that calculates the holidays *for your culture / environment* (there are many!)

Then, you have to iterate through the days from start to end date. This can be done pretty easily:

```
DateTime startTime = new DateTime(2011, 4, 1);
DateTime endTime = new DateTime(2012, 4, 1);
int numberOfHolidays;

for (DateTime currentDate = startTime; currentDate <= endTime currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1)) {
    if (isHoliday(currentDate) || isWeekendDay(currentDate))
      numberOfHolidays++;
}
```

You'll have to implement the methods `isHoliday` and `isWeekendDay` by your own, see the answer to the first question part.

Comment: Actually the requirement is to combine holidays and weekends to create a good vacation plan for user.  I dont need to worry about the country and religion because i have webservices to take care of getting holidays of a specific country and religion.

Comment: Ok, so that's the answer to question 1. Now, try to fetch these information from the website use e.g. my code to calculate the number of holidays. If you get stuck somewhere, ask a new, more specific, question